# How to delete multiple retained messages with LWT?

Tags: mqtt

From the documentation I've understood that LWT can send or delete one message. But if the client needs to have multiple retained messages, how can they be cleaned up when the connection is lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

The LWT will only send 1 message (or send an message with a null payload to clear a retained message).

If you want to alter the state of other retained messages the only real option is to have a separate client running subscribing to the LWT topics and it then clears the multiple retained messages.

Answer (score 1):

As hardillb mentioned, it's not possible with MQTT standard mechanisms. Some brokers may have options for deleting multiple retained messages, though. For HiveMQ there is a [RetainedMessageStore](http://www.hivemq.com/docs/plugins/latest/#retained-message-store) available that allows to modify the retained messages on events (e.g. when a LWT is sent). There's even a plugin that allows to delete retained messages recursively: [Github Link](https://github.com/hivemq/hivemq-delete-retained-messages-recursively-plugin)